# How to .jpg url image show on Imageview in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, imageview

I am using sdimage library to show  image on imageview with image url.
when i am using png url image it work perfectly but when i am using .jpg image format url then it don't show image on imageview. 
code:-

```
 let url = URL.init(string: "http://yeorder.com/api1/img/product/1494571262Nestle Cerelac Baby Cereal With Milk Wheat And Orange.jpg")
 imageview.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "logo"))
```

Comment: in here are you get the output `url`

Comment: when i am check the url in browser it show image but when i am using url in my imageview it dosn't work

Comment: you can do like this: let urlPath = URL(string: url!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL contains white spaces. xcode doesnot support whitespaces in url

"http://yeorder.com/api1/img/product/1494571262Nestle Cerelac Baby Cereal With Milk Wheat And Orange.jpg"

you need to change whitespace to %20 by using the below code

```
    var urlString = "http://yeorder.com/api1/img/product/1494571262Nestle Cerelac Baby Cereal With Milk Wheat And Orange.jpg"

    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

    let url = URL.init(string:urlString)

    imageview.sd_setImage(with: url , placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "logo"))
```

output of urlString : "http://yeorder.com/api1/img/product/1494571262Nestle%20Cerelac%20Baby%20Cereal%20With%20Milk%20Wheat%20And%20Orange.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

In your Image name have problem

try this

**Swift 3**

```
var urlString = "http://yeorder.com/api1/img/product/1494571262Nestle Cerelac Baby Cereal With Milk Wheat And Orange.jpg"

urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

let url = URL(string:urlString)
imageview.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

Comment: acutally you need to add `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`

Comment: i am adding "addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!" in my url and perfectly work thank you